# Will this code (command) work in a cron job, or do I need to put it into a file?

Tags: cron, command

Some commands I use (i.e rsync) work fine in cron jobs; Will this:

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

...or do I need to put it into a file? I can test it myself soon, however asking may save precious time.

Comment: To answer "...or do I need to put it into a file": `cron` uses `system()` to execute cronjobs, which gives the entire line to the `sh` shell (for example, `/bin/sh -c 'find ....'`). In other words, if a command can be used inside `sh`, it can be used in a cronjob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this will not work. You can't give a wildcard to specify the place where to search. Use the -name parameter instead, like this:

`find /path/to/files -name "*" -mtime +30 -print0 | xargs -0 rm`

I also made sure this command can handle lot's of files and files with spaces in it's name via the use of xargs instead of -exec.

Comment: Glad to get the improved version; Also confirmed it works as a cron job  :o)

Comment: Recent `find` versions support `-delete`.

Comment: `-name "*"` can be removed since it's implied. Recent versions of find support `-exec foo {} +` which gives similar results to using `xargs` (but `-delete` is all you need as grawity says).

Comment: Haven't tested the new comments yet / (remove -name "*") / (add -delete) / no 'xargs' or 'rm'  >>  find /path/to/files -mtime +30 -delete   >>> is that right?